# jQuery filter /selector

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="one">
    <span class="two">
        <span class="Three">
                <span class="Four">
                <a href=''>1</a>
                <a href=''>2</a>
                <a href=''>3</a>
                </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to select the first  `a` tag from `span class="one"`
Is this a right syntax?

```
$('span.one > a:firstchild')
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want to select direct child of `span.one` or `<a href=''>1</a>`
this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this . you have missed `-` in between first and child. this is to access direct child

```
 $('span.one > a:first-child')
```

reference : [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

**OR**

do you want to select `a` inside span.four from span.one

```
 $('span.one a:first-child')
```

Answer (score 2):

use `a:first-child` or `a:first` both should work

```
$('span.one a:first-child'); //or
$('span.one a:first')
```